# Label for File input in firefox

Tags: html, file-upload

When I add a label the a form input, I can normally click the label and it will refer me to the appropriate input (see below).

```
<label for="input">Label</label><input type="text" id="input"/>
```

However, when I try to accomplish the same with a file input, the click on the label gets ignored. Is this a bug? A "feature"? And is there any way to still accomplish this?

jsFiddle testcase: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bK6RZ/)

Comment: Worked for me:  Chrome 14 on OSX

Comment: This worked for me on FF6, but only through keyboard navigation - using the mouse, it didn't (making an assumption that it should) correctly focus the file input.

Comment: It does not work in FF 7.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: It does not work in FF 10.0.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label's prescribed behavior differs between HTML specifications.

More precisely, this is probably a bug in FF (rather than an extra feature in the others), because this behavior should usually be included according to the HTML 4 spec:
[When a LABEL element receives focus, it passes the focus on to its associated control. See the section below on access keys for examples.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)

The [current HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-label-element) is more nuanced, but does indicate the possibility that it do nothing (this is the expected behavior in iOS).

Comment: Just wanted to point out had sad I get when people cite w3schools... let's just say they're not at all credible. Please see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: +1 @MusikAnimal it is just amazing how such an inaccurate source is so popular (at least judging how high they are ranked in google's results)