# Workaround for file input label click (Firefox)

Tags: html, firefox, file-upload, label

```
<label for="input">Label</label><input type="file" id="input"/>
```

In Firefox 7 it is not possible to trigger the open file dialog by clicking on the label.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516882/label-for-file-input-in-firefox) is very similar but that's green checked with *it's a bug in FF*. I'm looking for a workaround.

Any ideas?

Comment: Kan ju tillägga att det inte fungerar under FF.4 på Ubuntu-maskin...

Can just add that it is even not working in FF.4 under Ubuntu.

Comment: @maxxie Can you try the workaround I posted on your machine?

Comment: Note: It looks like a fix for this bug is set to be released soon https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701353

Comment: Great news, this is fixed in Firefox 23 (I confirmed with latest dev build), which I expect will release in August of 2013. Until then, if you want to use latest jQuery without the migrate plugin, you can use this shim: http://greatwebguy.com/jquery-2/browser-detection-shim-for-jquery-1-9/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

thank you for this q&a... helped me out.

my variation of @marten-wikstrom's solution:

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
  $(document).on('click', 'label', function(e) {
    if(e.currentTarget === this && e.target.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
      $(this.control).click();
    }
  });
}
```

notes

- using document.ready (`$(function() {...});`) is unnecessary, in either solution.  `jQuery.fn.live` takes care of that in @marten-wikstrom's case;  explicitly binding to `document` does in my example.
- using `jQuery.fn.on`... current recommended binding technique.
- added the `!== 'INPUT'` check to ensure execution does not get caught in a loop here:

  ```
  <label>
    <input type="file">
  </label>
  ```

  (since the file field click will bubble back up to the label)
- change `event.target` check to `event.currentTarget`, allowing for initial click on the `<em>` in:

  ```
  <label for="field">click <em>here</em></label>
  ```
- using the label element's `control` attribute for cleaner, simpler, spec-base form field association.

Comment: just want to give an update and my thoughts, not meant to be mr. knowitall ;) `$.browser` is obsolete since jquery 1.9. and `jquery.on()` on the document is kinda rude. try to narrow it down, closer to the element (performance). or why use the deligate variant anyways..? `$("label[name=input]").on("click",function() {...});` should do the trick as well..

Comment: just a side note: after the release of jQuery 1.9+ u can only use $.browser.VENDOR if you include the jquery.migrate plugin. Or use something like modernizr for browser detection.

Comment: Note that this issue has been fixed in FF 22, so the script double opens the file dialog. I suggested the following script update, but oddly enough it was rejected by the reviewers, still the suggested script works properly. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2481980

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a feasible workaround:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("label").click(function () {
            $("#input").click();
        });
    });
</script>
<label for="input">Label</label><input type="file" id="input"/>
```

Quite strange that FF allows you to simulate a click on a file input. I thought that was considered a security risk...

**UPDATE:** This is a generic workaround:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            $("label").live("click", function (event) {
                if (event.target == this) {
                    $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).extend($("input", this)).first().click();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But still I thinks it's little stupid that it don't work with the normal `<label for="input">....`....

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems arise when using the jQuery browser detection, most notably the anti-pattern of using browser detection rather than feature detection, in addition to the fact that 1.9+ doesn't provide that functionality.

Perhaps, then, the solution I arrived at is a bit hypocritical, but it worked well and seems to adhere to most best practices today.

First, ensure you're using [Paul Irish's conditional  classes](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/). Then, use something like:

```
  if($("html").hasClass("ie")) {
    $("label").click();
  } else {
    $("input").click();
  }
```

Otherwise, I found the event would be double-fired in browsers such as Chrome. This solution seemed elegant enough.

Answer (score 1):

The file-selection dialog can be triggered in all browsers by the [`click()` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click%28%29_method). An unobtrusive solution to this problem could look like that:

```
$('label')
    .attr('for', null)
    .click(function() {
        $('#input').click();
    });
```

Removing the `for` attribute is important since other browsers (e.g. Chrome, IE) will still ratify it and show the dialog twice.

I tested it in Chrome 25, Firefox 19 and IE 9 and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be fixed in FF 23, so browser detection becomes hazardous and leads to double system dialogs ;(

You can add another test to restrict the fix to FF version prior to version 23:

```
if(parseInt(navigator.buildID,10) < 20130714000000){
  //DO THE FIX
}
```

It's quite ugly, but this fix will be removed as soon as old the version of FF will have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

A work around when you don't need/want to have the input box (like image upload) is to use `opacity: 0` in the element and use `pointer-events: none;` in the label.
The solution is really design specific but maybe should work for someone who comes to this. (until now the bug doesn't been fixed)

http://codepen.io/octavioamu/pen/ByOQBE

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of the label and input elements. iow, put the label element after the input element.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the label in Firefox. Even if I put the label element after the input element. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

you can dispatch the event from any event to the type=file input if you want
make the input display:none and visibility:hidden, and then dispatch the event from,
say, the click|touch of an image ...

```
<img id="customImg" src="file.ext"/>
<input id="fileLoader" type="file" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"/>

<script>
    customImg.addEventListener(customImg.ontouchstart?'touchstart':'click', function(e){
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click',false,true);
        fileLoader.dispatchEvent(evt);
    },false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of Corey above in a `React` environment I had to do the following:

(Firefox check is based on: [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser))

```js
const ReactFileInputButton = ({ onClick }) => {

    const isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

    const handleClick = isFirefox ? (e) => {
        e.currentTarget.control.click();
    } : undefined;

    const handleFileSelect = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            onClick({ file: e.target.files[0] });
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" id="file" onChange={handleFileSelect} />
            <label htmlFor="file" onClick={handleClick}>
                Select file
            </label>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" 
onclick="document.getElementById('uploadImage').click(event);" />
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };
</script>
```